# Remote desktop services licensing activation and errors for windows server 2022?

Tags: remote-desktop, licensing, remote-desktop-services

**Question Remote desktop services licensing activation and errors for windows server 2022?**

**Setup history**
In my small coaching institue computer lab with 25pc. 15 pc are Independet desktops and 10 are thin client ncomputing (remote desktop) diskless CPU less.

i had made I7 server machine have installed Multi booting with windows server 2022 evaluation installed with programming and multimedia application for teaching purposes.

I am running Domain controller in windows server 2022 and restricted with  group polices and created different  OU (organisation units) and users  for 15 independet pc and  different OU for ncomputing remote desktop users.Gave OU users permission and member of remote desktop services  group.

When i installed Remote desktop services it worked succesfully  with  ncomputing clients and all 5 machines worked sucessfully. But gave an error "Remote desktop mode is not configured " and services will stop in 120 days.
[image: Remote desktop mode is not configured]

After googling i  found solution and it said to  modify registry and group policy  and activate the remote desktop services licensing. i did all.

1. Group policies  editing & Registry editing
   [Group policy and registry editing](https://itblog.ldlnet.net/index.php/2020/06/24/remote-desktop-licensing-mode-is-not-configured-when-configuring-remote-desktop-services/)
2. Remote desktop  services licensing  [Remote desktop  services licensing](https://%20https://digitalproductkey.com/how-to-install-and-activate-windows-server-2022-rds-cals/)

But after registry setting activations and group policies the client coudnt connect to the server and get black  screeen after botting and windows login in client machines.

Now the remote desktop sevices licencing is displaying "0" users are allowed whereas in group policy i had allowed conncetion to 100.

[image: remote desktop services troubleshooting]

after activation its giving errors and asking to install licencence is there any way to bypass it.

[image: licensee]
[image: license key]

[image: license key to install]

for  solutions kindly share any link for step by step procedure to  solve the problem

Thank you in advance for reading and asnwering will be great help for resolving the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)